# different variables with the same name in a sas dataset

Tags: input, sas

I have a text file where two different columns are having the same name. As shown in the following figure.[image]

Let's say for `SystBP`, I need to change the first `SystBP` to `SystBP_B` and the second `SystBP` to `SystBP_E`.

Could someone kindly offer me some help on this?

Comment: That looks like a report not a dataset.  Are you sure the first row isn't stored as two observations with different values of SESSION, START and END.

Comment: Dear @Tom, thank you for your reply. this is actually one dataset in txt format.

Comment: As SAS users when we say _data set_, we mean a SAS data set, and that CAN NOT have two fields with the same name. Therefore, I updated your question.

Comment: In what EDI are you developing, SAS EG?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When programming in SAS Base You should sometimes not expect SAS to read column names from a text file and interpret them as variable names.

You have to instruct SAS what the first data row is, where the values are written and how they should be interpreted (text, number, date, ...) You do that with an `infile` and an `input` statement in a data step.

As you write the code yourself, you have complete control.

```
data READ_FROM_TXT;
    infile "C:\myFolder\myFile.txt" firstobs=3 truncover; 
        * firstobs=3 makes SAS skip the first 2 observations;
        * truncover avoids jumping to the next line when the last variable is missing or too short ;
    input 
        @01 ID         2.
        @05 Week       4.
        @11 SystBP_B   6.
        @19 DiastBP_B  6.
        ...
        @41 SystBP_E   6.
        @49 DiastBP_E  6.
        ...
        ;
        * @11 SystBP_B   6. instructs SAS to interpret positions 11 to 16 as a number 
        * and assign the value to variable SystBP_B;
run;
```

As you inserted the data as an image, not as text, using markup, I had to guess the positions, so you will have to correct them.

Answer (score 1):

I would make timing into observations.

```
data test;
   infile cards4 firstobs=2;
   input id :$8. week @;
   do time = 'STR','END';
      input SystBP  DiastBP   Pulse   Stress @;
      output;
      end;
   cards;
ID Week  SystBP  DiastBP   Pulse   Stress   SystBP  DiastBP   Pulse   Stress
1   1      134       44      66      5.8      134       44      66      5.8
;;;;
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `INFILE` option `FIRSTOBS=` will let you `INPUT` the data starting in row 3.

Data file: `C:\temp\bp-survey.txt`

```
         Start                               End
ID Week  SystBP  DiastBP   Pulse   Stress   SystBP  DiastBP   Pulse   Stress
1   1      134       44      66      5.8      134       44      66      5.8
...
```

Program

```
filename  survey 'c:\temp\bp-survey.txt';

data want;
  infile survey firstobs=3;
  input 
    ID Week
    SystBP_start DiastBP_start Pulse_start Stress_start
    SystBP_end   DiastBP_end   Pulse_end   Stress_end
  ;
run;

ods html ;
proc print data=want;
run;
```